# OAUTHBEARER authentication fails in mutt

Tags: authentication, mutt, imap, gmail

I've used `OAUTHBEARER` authentication to use `mutt` with GMail for a while, but I've run into a an issue that I can't figure out. When I launch `mutt` I get `OAUTHBEARER authentication failed`. Here is `.muttdebug0`:

```
[2020-08-27 10:38:59] TLSv1.3 connection using TLSv1.3 (TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)
[2020-08-27 10:39:00] Connected to imap.gmail.com:993 on fd=7
[2020-08-27 10:39:00] imap_cmd_step: grew buffer to 512 bytes
[2020-08-27 10:39:00] 7< * OK Gimap ready for requests from XX.XX.XX.XX r65mb112981108pjg
[2020-08-27 10:39:00] IMAP queue drained
[2020-08-27 10:39:00] 7> a0000 CAPABILITY
[2020-08-27 10:39:00] 7< * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN AUTH=OAUTHBEARER AUTH=XOAUTH
[2020-08-27 10:39:00] Handling CAPABILITY
[2020-08-27 10:39:00] 7< a0000 OK Thats all she wrote! r65mb112981108pjg
[2020-08-27 10:39:00] IMAP queue drained
[2020-08-27 10:39:00] imap_authenticate: Trying method oauthbearer
[2020-08-27 10:39:00] Authenticating (OAUTHBEARER)...
[2020-08-27 10:39:00] 7> a0001 AUTHENTICATE OAUTHBEARER bixhPWN3YWxrYXRyb25AZ21haWwuXXXXX=
[2020-08-27 10:39:01] 7< + eyJXXXXXXX29nbGUuY29tLyJ9
[2020-08-27 10:39:01] 7> [2020-08-27 10:39:01] OAUTHBEARER authentication failed.
```

I have a project set up in the **Google Dev console** and a `client_id` and `client_secret`. I get a warning that I have to specifically ignore about my Google Developer app being **unverified** that I have to explicitly allow. I don't remember this being an issue in the past. I can successfully log in using:

```
oauth2.py --user=myemail@gmail.com --client_id=56843257498 --client_secret=fjdksla --generate_oauth2_token
```

This is in my `.muttrc`:

```
set imap_oauth_refresh_command="~me/bin/oauth2.py \
    --user myemail@gmail.com \
    --client_id=60080XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com \
    --client_secret=AZXXXX \
    --refresh_token=1//XXXXAYSNwF"
set smtp_oauth_refresh_command="~me/bin/oauth2.py \
    --user=myemail@gmail.com \
    --client_id=60080XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com \
    --client_secret=AZXXXX \
    --refresh_token=1//XXXXAYSNwF"
```

The above commands run fine in a shell. Also, a test with `oauth2.py` **succeeds** as well (though this tests `XOAUTH2` and not `OAUTHBEARER`).

```
  10:30.51 > HNNF1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2
  10:30.54 < +
  10:30.54 write literal size 280
  10:31.24 < * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- SPECIAL-USE APPENDLIMIT=35651584
  10:31.24 < HNNF1 OK myemail@gmail.com authenticated (Success)
  10:31.24 > HNNF2 SELECT INBOX
  10:31.50 < * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Forwarded $Junk $NotJunk $NotPhishing $Phishing)
  10:31.50 < * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Forwarded $Junk $NotJunk $NotPhishing $Phishing \*)] Flags permitted.
  10:31.50 < * OK [UIDVALIDITY 2] UIDs valid.
  10:31.50 < * 1060 EXISTS
  10:31.50 < * 0 RECENT
  10:31.50 < * OK [UIDNEXT 51915] Predicted next UID.
  10:31.50 < * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 5748372]
  10:31.50 < HNNF2 OK [READ-WRITE] INBOX selected. (Success)
```

I have this all set up and working for my work email, but not for my personal. I feel like I'm just missing something simple. Can anyone help me see my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out. I had a change in my `oauth2.py` that printed the json response instead of just the `access_token`. `mutt` was passing the base64-encoded json as the bearer token which is not correct. Thanks to @jakub-jindra for pointing me toward the `--quiet` option.

I figured this out by running `mutt -d 5` which shows the base64-encoded payload that it passes to GMail:

```
[2020-08-28 10:00:54] Authenticating (OAUTHBEARER)...
[2020-08-28 10:00:54] 7> a0001 AUTHENTICATE OAUTHBEARER XXXXXXXXXX$XXXXInfQEB
[2020-08-28 10:00:55] 7< + XXXXXXXXXX
[2020-08-28 10:00:55] 7> [2020-08-28 10:00:55] OAUTHBEARER authentication failed.
```

I base-64 decoded that and got:

```
n,a=myemail@gmail.com,host=imap.gmail.comport=993auth=Bearer {u'access_token': u'ya29.a0XXXXXX', u'scope': u'https://mail.google.com/', u'expires_in': 3599, u'token_type': u'Bearer'}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

According to example in [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#oauth) or [neomutt](https://neomutt.org/guide/optionalfeatures.html#6-%C2%A0oauthbearer-support) docs the script oauth2.py in `{smtp,imap,pop}_oauth_refresh_command` should include `--quiet` option.

It's not clear from the documentation that this is important. But I've just tested it on mine setup with SMTP. Without the option I'm getting authentication error also.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I tried it with `--quiet` and get the same error.